# How to remove existing CIFilter from video in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, video, cifilter

```
func removeFilterFromVideo(videoURL: URL, completion: @escaping ((URL?, String?) -> Void)) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
    
    // Create a mutable video composition
    guard let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        completion(nil, "Failed to load video track")
        return
    }

This function is not working i am not getting any errors.
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset) { request in
        // Provide the original image to the composition
        request.finish(with: request.sourceImage, context: nil)
    }
    
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
    
    // Export session
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        completion(nil, "Failed to create export session")
        return
    }
    
    // Create output file URL
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let outputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("NoFilterVideo").appendingPathExtension("mp4")
    
    // Remove existing file
    deleteFile(outputURL)
    
    // Configure export session
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
    
    // Perform export asynchronously
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        switch exportSession.status {
        case .completed:
            completion(outputURL, nil)
        case .failed, .cancelled:
            completion(nil, exportSession.error?.localizedDescription)
        default:
            completion(nil, "Failed to export video")
        }
    }
}
```

This function is not working, i am not getting any error though. I want to remove all existing CIFilter before adding a new one currently it's adding filter on top. Working on video edit tool.

Comment: It seems likely that when you save your video to a file, any filters are applied destructively to the contents, and can't be removed (unless there is an invert filter that reverses the changes applied by the filrst filter.

Comment: So there should be a reverse filter for every filter right? for example what should be the reverse filter for this: CISharpenLuminance.

Comment: No, many CI filters are truly destructive. They alter the original image in a way that loses information. Sharpening is one such transformation. It alters the source image in away that can't be undone, at least not perfectly. You could apply a blur filter to attempt to reverse the sharpening, but the result will be degraded.

Comment: If you want to make filters truly reversible you should save the original video, and apply your filter(s) to that original. If the user decides to remove a filter, go back to the original image and apply any remaining filters to the oringinal.